# MVC controller calling view and postback view at the same time?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this mentally disturbing problem where I used the name View for my Views. As normal, created the initial page and the postback to save.

```
public ActionResult View(int id)
{
    Models.PageContent model = Controllers.PageContent.Get(id);
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult View(Models.PageContent model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Controllers.PageContent.UpdatePageContent(model.PageContentID, model.Title, model.Text);

        ViewBag.Success = true;
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

What is weird is that both the normal view and the post back view get called and it just doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe I'm just half asleep this morning, but I don't understand what you mean when you say, "normal view and the post back view get called." Are you saying that if the browser requests http://localhost/Foo/View/1 that it executes both actions? Or are you saying that if one of the actions executes it returns both views?

Comment: You're going to have to rename your View() function or change the parameters. Look at return View(model)...where should that go? It calls the other View (action) of course! (The HttpPost handler)

Comment: change the action name, if model validation fails you're calling the same action, instead of the View() function

Comment: @CraigW. What happens is that first the /Foo/View/1 executes, but straight afterwards, without even returning to the browsers the `[HttpPost]` Action executes, with the model from the "GET" Action. @MikeC Why do i have to rename View? Is it a special name. I want to "View" first, then postback to the HTTPPOST Action when pressing Save. This is a normal way that always worked. Why do Both methods get called on the same stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, okay, that makes sense then as to what is happening. In your `View(int id)` method you're calling `View(model)`, where `model` is of type `PageContent`. When .NET tries to resolve overloaded methods it picks the most specific, which would be the method right below in the same controller. The method that is in the base control is actually defined as `View(Object model)` which is less specific than `View(PageContent model)`, so it resolves the call to the HttpPost version of the method rather than the base class version of the method.

The comment about changing the name of the method is correct. Your choice of method name is conflicting with the framework-provided `View` method.

If you want to use `View` in the URL you can use the `ActionName` attribute.

```
[ActionName( "View" )]
public ActionResult GetView( int id )

[HttpPost]
[ActionName( "View" )]
public ActionResult PostView( Models.PageContent model )
```

Comment: Why would VisualStudio not warm us about this. It really means that the word View is being resolved to the class `View()` instead of treating it like a variable. You see the syntax parsers in VS2013 don't even highlight the word `View` in blue, as it would any Class, it plain black. So if change `View` to `Edit`, It works like it should. So, does that mean I cannot use any word in the action, that is a class in the namespace?

Comment: The word `View` is never a variable. And in the statement `return View(model)` it's not a class, it's a method. `View()` is a convenience method declared on the base controller class that is basically a shortcut for `new ViewResult(model)`.

Answer (score 0):

I did a test at home on my VS2013 and I actually got a green squiggly to warn me. For some reason,on both mine and another developers this did not show. Possibly because it was MVC3 and not 4 like my test.

[image]